# SQL Server rollback behaviour after incrementing a counter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, rollback

If I have a stored procedure with an UPDATE that includes:

```
SET attendeeCount = attendeeCount + @incrementBy
```

and later in the transaction I rollback, is attendeecount decremented from it's current value (which may have changed), or is it just reset to it's original value before the transaction?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: That would depend on whether 'attendeeCount ' is a column in a table variable or a table.

Comment: @MitchWheat it's a regular table update.

Comment: Slight aside to the question asked: I wouldn't have an `attendeeCount` column. This information should be easily calculated at run-time from your attendees/tickets/scans table. Maintaining this count yourself is not worth the effort, IMO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `attendeeCount` is an ordinary column in a table (be it normal or temporary table), its value will be reverted back to what it was before transaction has started. The only situations when the behaviour is different are:

- column with the `identity` attribute. The value will be rolled back, but internal `identity` counter will not. The same goes for sequences.
- columns in table variables. These are unaffected by rollbacks.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that might be the case. The rollback in this stored proc is used to handle simultanious booking of the last ticket. But the rollback itself can cause the count to go out of sync if others are changing the value in between.

Comment: @AndyEwer, unless it's `identity` (and, by the looks of your code, it isn't) nothing will go out of sync, because other writers will wait for your lock to be released. However, locking and concurrency are topics which are a bit too big to fit them into a single SO comment.